# check character string

Tags: java, etl, talend

hello I would like to test if the string contains the character _ then we do `stringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9),"_","S")` nothing else. I do not know how to do it with talend who can help me

```
 row1.B.contains("_")?StringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9),"_","S")
```

Comment: can u provide some standard inputs and expected output?

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helped you.  That way people know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ternary operator(? :) in this case as it needs assignment operator in left and tow choices in the right(not suitable).

For single character present check, I prefer `indexOf` as below:

```
  if(row1.B != null && row1.B.indexOf('_')>=0){
     StringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9),"_","S");
 }
```

Comment: @user91599: What error? I assume `row1.B` is the string, correct?

Comment: @user91599 There should be some error stack traces stating what is the system error. Can you share that? Also can you confirm, `row1.B` is string or not? My answer is just around finding the character presence in the string, which shouldn't be failing.